# Подключение к imap через proxy Java

Tags: java, proxy, imap

Я пытаюсь подключиться по imap через прокси сервер, вот мой код

```
            String proxyIP = "myip";
            String proxyPort = "port";
            String proxyUser = "login";
            String proxyPassword = "pass";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.host", proxyIP);
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.port", proxyPort);
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.user", proxyUser);
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.password", proxyPassword);

            Session eSession = Session.getInstance(prop);

            Store eStore = eSession.getStore("imaps");
            eStore.connect(imap, email, password);

            Folder eFolder = eStore.getFolder("Inbox");
            eFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            System.out.println("Email прошел проверку! Колличество писем: " + eFolder.getMessageCount());
            return true;
```

После запуска я не получаю никаких ошибок, и получаю доступ к почте, но подключение происходит без прокси. Что я делаю не так?

Спасибо большое!

Comment: "но подключение происходит без прокси" - а можно вот этот момент рассказать поподробнее? Как Вы видите, что подключение происходит без прокси?

Comment: Я использую подключение к gmail, после попытки подключиться происходит разрыв соединения т.к не разрешены сомнительные imap клиенты, после я получаю оповещение системы безопасности которая мне говорит местоположение на основе моего IP и это не местоположение моего прокси сервера.

Comment: В случае если разрешены сторонние небезопасные клиенты происходит то же самое, но я могу подключиться к почте. Факт в том что гугл видит мой ip несмотря на то что я использую приватные прокси как ipv4 так и 6